# Smart linking for resources?

Tags: javascript

I have a somewhat annoying issue... I have a JS function which toggles the image of an element on a certain event (click). This function is executed on multiple pages.

In the js, I have a like that goes like so:

```
img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../assets/img.png)';
```

Everything works perfectly fine when the function is being called from a file that exists in a different folder... Folder structure is like so:

- /project

  - /assets
  - /html
  - /js
  - index.html

Notice the index file sitting the parent folder? When I execute the function from this index.html file, the images can't be found (Since the JS is looking outside the parent folder thanks to the '../'), but it works for all other pages inside the html folder, since the relative path finding will go out to the parent folder, and then into assets...

Anyway I can make this smart without having to resort to other completely different approaches? I know I can just rely on some CSS here, add and remove classes to toggle images instead of directly changing the image source...

Its odd though, the relative path works from css where the css behaves as the anchor for the path finder... But if you use JS to change the css property, the html file becomes the anchor...

Comment: try to write the path relative to the index.html file

Comment: Yeah, see, the relative path from the index.html file will be simply "assets/img.png", but because I'm setting the path for the file dynamically, the html file that calls the path is different... So, its not just index.html, but also /html/text.html... And that's where the cheese is semi rotten...

Answer (score 0):

```
img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("assets/img.png")';
```

Comment: nice, how about some explanation? plus your code has the exact same effect, if not wrong, since the path is different so its actually not correct

Comment: Nope... I tried it, doesn't work... Same issue, in that the index.html file will not be able to find the images, as it'll path itself outside the parent folder...

Comment: sorry about that, I forgot to delete the first "/".
when using ../ in front of a path it means that your path starts from the parent folder, not from the current one

Answer (score 0):

Make the path relative to site NOT the current page or style sheet.

When including a relative url in CSS the url is relative to CSS's url, which is I assume is in the assets folder.

```
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/assets/img.png")';
```

Comment: doing this, sets the path to begin from root... Basically, its now looking for a folder called 'assets' in my C: drive... Lol...

Comment: Use url(/project/assets/img.png); where project is the name of your website folder.

Comment: Hmmm... Is this considered absolute linking? I'm somewhat new to this... My understanding was that absolute linking required the provision of the FULL, actual path...